# Android: App Not Previewing in AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have been working with this issue for two days now, as I am new to Android development.  I am using Eclipse, and when I choose to launch the app, the AVD starts, the screen is black for a few seconds and then the animation "Android" appears and nothing happens past that point.  I thought it was loading at first until I have left it opened for nearly an hour and nothing ever happens.

The console reads

```
[2013-01-01 20:52:57 - FirstApp] Android Launch!
[2013-01-01 20:52:57 - FirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-01-01 20:52:57 - FirstApp] Performing com.example.firstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-01-01 20:52:58 - FirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google'
[2013-01-01 20:52:58 - FirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google'`
```

As I said, I am new to this and if I fail to mention any other necessary components it is merely because I do not know where else to search for this solution.

Thanks for any of your help.

Comment: Two questions: 1) If you launch an AVD normally (via the manager), does it launch properly? 2) If not, try running the emulator from the command line/terminal and see if it outputs any error messages.

Comment: Okay, when I launch AVD via the manager, the exact thing happens as I described when I launch the project via AVD.  Then via the terminal after I ran `adb install bin/FirstApp-debug.apk` the terminal reads: `error: device not found
- waiting for device -`

Comment: Launch the emulator from the terminal (this doesn't have anything to do with adb). Try doing `emulator -avd <name>` to see if any messages come up.

Comment: I wasn't even aware emulator was a command.  Anywho, I run `emulator -avd FirstApp` and get:
`PANIC: Could not open: FirstApp`

Comment: If I type emulator at all I get `PANIC: Missing arch-specific emulator program: emulator-arm` I can't even get a --help option out of it.  Is there a man for this?

Comment: You're missing the `emulator-arm` executable which *is* needed to emulate - it is the basis of all the non-intel emulators. You should look into reinstalling the emulator (via the Android sdk tools) Based on the panic though, it does seem that the SDK tools installed the wrong binaries for your OS.

Comment: Ohhh I see, well I downloaded the whole package from the Google Android Developer's site, so I do not think I 'manually' installed an emulator.  However, I will try and figure out how to do so.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have finally got the emulator working and here are my errors: `emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: \ libOpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory \
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.` Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't dealt with Linux AVDs. SO seems to have some answers though, hopefully they can help.

Comment: That's alright man, I am just going to set it up on my Windows Computer, it seems as if the whole setup is much more convenient.

Comment: You can very well run your app even though you see the errors/warnings posted above.
Just follow the answer that I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a very annoying issue for all the Android beginners.
At first, I too used to stare at the 'Android' animation for minutes and hours and just wonder.

WORKING WITH ANDROID EMULATOR:

```
1. Always start the AVD before directly running an application.  
Emulators usually take a considerable amount of time to load before you can  
actually try to run an app.  
2. Change the timeout settings by Window-->Preferences-->Android-->DDMS-->ADB  
Connection TimeOut. Set it to say 50000.  
3. Once the AVD has loaded fully(there is usually a homescreen kind of display  
after the 'Android' animation you mentioned), then run your app as right-click-->  
Run as Android Application  
4.Sometimes, there is a keypad lock on the emulator display just like a phone, so  
you might have to manually unlock the display before you can see the running app
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!  So I have a few questions.  So I start the AVD before the application?  So does that mean whenever I add new changes to my app, I right click Run as Android Application again? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I get this error `[2013-01-02 16:53:37 - Emulator] 
[2013-01-02 16:53:39 - MyFirstApp] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2013-01-02 16:53:39 - MyFirstApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...` This happened quite a few times, and it never launches. =/